# Filtrar productos con fetch en React

Tags: json, reactjs, api

Estoy trabajando con una fake api y un json local y estoy intentando filtrar los productos por categoría pero no lo estoy logrando hacer.

Tengo un componente con estos botones:

```
<div className='categories'>
   <ul className='categories-list'>
      <li><button >Todos</button></li>
      <li><button >Aromas</button></li>
      <li><button >Cocina</button></li>
      <li><button >Mantas y almohadones</button></li>
      <li><button >Baño y laundry</button></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

y en otro componente en donde tengo el fetch con el json que tiene el array de productos:

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './ItemList.css'
import Item from '../item/Item'

 const ItemList = (props) => {
   const [productos,setProductos] = useState([])
   useEffect(()=>{
      fetch('../../misProductos.json')
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(json => setProductos(json.map(productos => <Item key={productos.id} id= 
          {"producto" + 
          productos.id} data={productos}/>)))
    },[])
    return(
    <div>
        {productos}
    </div>
    )
}
export default ItemList
```

Quiero que al hacer clic en cada botón aparezcan los productos que en el json tienen esa categoría.
Sé que puedo hacerlo con `context` pero quiero evitar usarlo.

Comment: y que has intentado?, en el codigo insertado no se demuestra esfuerzo ni intencion de realizar lo que propones, tampoco muestras la estructura de los datos (el json que te responde la api). Teniendo esto es cuenta dudo que puedan ayudarte porfavor  lee [ask] y [example]

Comment: @David081, cuando editas una pregunta/respuesta, no olvides editar además los errores de tipeo/ortográficos :)